# Three sets A, B and C so that any two intersect is an infinite set, but the intersection of all three is empty.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been thinking about this for a while, but I can't really find an example of three sets that can fit the criteria. Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider the sets $(1,2) \cup (3,4)$, $(3,4) \cup (5,6)$ and $(1,2) \cup (5,6)$.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the infinite part, let $A=\{0,1\},B=\{0,2\},C=\{1,2\}$. Can you fix this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a triangle, with each edge representing a set in $\mathbb R^2$.

If we thicken the triangle (by taking the cartesian product of each edge with an appropriate interval in the orthogonal direction), we get thickened edges.

Now, any two of the three sets will intersect at a "thickened point", which will be infinite as it will have non-zero measure. However, if you make your triangle large enough and the thickening small enough, then you will get the intersection of all three of the thickened sets as empty.

If you want four sets instead of three, consider a thickened tetrahedron instead,with the sets now being thickened triangles, and use the same logic.

In fact, if you can figure out the pattern between tetrahedrons and triangles, you can get the same result for any finite number of sets, by embedding in $\mathbb R^n$, for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set of all multiples of three, $B$ be the set of all multiples of five and $C$ be the set of all multiples of three or five that are not multiples of fifteen.

Answer (score 0):

Draw two equilateral triangles that are concentric (I won't define concentricity leaving it for you to figure out)   of side length 10 and 9 centimetres respectively.

Now extend the sides of inner triangle on both ends to meet the outer triangle.

You can regard this as some kind of a jogging track on a triangular park.

The three sets are  the three strips on the border. Any two strips meet near the corner. But there is no point common to all the three strips. All these sets (including the intersections) are planar regions of positive area and hence contain infinitely many points.